# How to change the length of axis in quiver

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use `plt.quiver` to do a vector plot. I got two arrays specifying U and V value, they are both 21 x 17 size.

[image: Vector Plot]

I saw from the matplotlib website that:

units: [ ‘width’ | ‘height’ | ‘dots’ | ‘inches’ | ‘x’ | ‘y’ | ‘xy’ ]
Arrow units; the arrow dimensions except for length are in multiples of this unit.

**‘width’ or ‘height’: the width or height of the axes**

But I did not manage to use it, so I am wondering how to change the length of axis, and also how to plot the image in rectangle rather than square.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
plt.axis('equal');
```

so the x-axis and the y-axis have the same scale.

In the [manual](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html) you find:

> scale : None, float, optional Number of data units per arrow length
>   unit, e.g., m/s per plot width; a smaller scale parameter makes the
>   arrow longer. Default is None.

A quick and dirty solution however might be:

```
myScale = 5.5
plt.quiver(x,y, myScale*u, myScale*v)
```

Comment: Thank You! I already solved the problem by using the plt.axis.
I set it as :
plt.axis(xmin=0, xmax=16, ymin=0, ymax=20).
So that it makes the x axis max. at 16 not 20.

Also, I found other useful function from the command too! Many Thanks!

Comment: it should be 17 and 21 in this case..typo

Answer (score 0):

To change the length and height of the figure you can specify the figure size e.g.:

```
plt.figure(figsize=[15,10]) # figsize=[width, height] (in inches)
```

I find its easier to change the length of the quivers by specifying  the scale:

```
plt.quiver(x,y,u,v,scale=10)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank You!
The plt.figure did help to change the shape of the image.

Comment: @RickyLau If you add your code give you more help with the size of the vectors